# Error with selenium import - ImportError: No module named selenium

Tags: python, macos, selenium

There's probably a million other questions asking the same thing, but I've gone through all of them today and I still can't find a solution to my question.

I'm developing a simple Instagram bot using selenium, and I recently started a new project (Using VS Code)

```
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep

browser = webdriver.Chrome()

browser.get("https://www.instagram.com/")

sleep(5)

browser.close()
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/tay/Desktop/Bot/run.py", line 1, in <module>
    from selenium import webdriver
ImportError: No module named selenium
```

Selenium was working for a previous project, but now is not. I have checked multiple times and I am sure that selenium is definitely installed on my Mac. Currently running python version 3.10.0, and I get the 'requirement already satisfied' message when I do `pip install selenium`

Could someone please explain what is wrong? I have gone as far as to reinstall both by IDE and selenium but still with no success.

Comment: Can you try running `pip3 install selenium` and then `python3 run.py` in your command prompt?

Comment: Try using the python IDLE for the same task . Do you have other python versions installed too ?

Comment: run in code `print( sys.executable )` to get `/full/path/to/python` which is used by this code. And later use `/full/path/to/python -m pip install ...` to install module with correct Python.

Comment: BTW: you may check `pip -V` to see if this `pip` installs modules for currernt Python. DIfferent versions don't share modules. Every Python need own `pip` and often you may have `pip`, `pip3`, `pip3.9`, `pip3.10` to install module for different Pythons. Or sometimes it is simpler to use Python to install modules - `python -m pip install ...`

Answer (score 1):

Possibly you have multiple versions of *Python* installed. So instead of using *pip* as:

```
pip install selenium
```

try to use *`pip3`* as:

```
pip3 install selenium
```